# While splitting rows into worksheets, need to copy multi-line header and paste values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm splitting Excel rows into individual worksheets based on names and including the newly created worksheets in the current workbook. I would like to include the header from the source workbook as the first 3 rows in each of the individual worksheets.  In addition to the first 3 row header, I need to paste the rows as values.  I know the code for pasting values is `PasteSpecial _ Operation:=xlPasteValues` but I'm not sure where to place it.  The code is attached. Feel free to totally refactor it if desired.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Sub SplitToWorksheets()
Dim ColHead As String
Dim ColH As Range
Dim iCol As Integer
Dim iRow As Long 'row index 
Dim Lrow As Integer 'row index on individual destination sheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet 'destination worksheet
Dim wsActive As Worksheet 'active worksheet
TryAgain:
ColHead = InputBox("Enter Column Heading", "Identify Column", [c1].Value)
If ColHead = "" Then Exit Sub
Set ColHeadCell = Rows(1).Find(ColHead, LookAt:=xlWhole)
If ColHeadCell Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Heading not found in row 1"
GoTo TryAgain
End If
Set wsActive = ActiveSheet
iCol = ColHeadCell.Column
'loop through values in selected column
For iRow = 4 To wsActive.Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
If Not SheetExists(CStr(wsActive.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)) Then
Set wsDest = Worksheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
wsDest.Name = CStr(wsActive.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value)
wsActive.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Rows(1)
Else
Set wsDest = Worksheets(CStr(wsActive.Cells(iRow, iCol).Value))
End If
Lrow = wsDest.Cells(65536, iCol).End(xlUp).Row
wsActive.Rows(iRow).Copy Destination:=wsDest.Rows(Lrow + 1)
Next iRow
End Sub


Function SheetExists(SheetId As Variant) As Boolean
'Checks to see if the sheet exists
Dim sh As Object
On Error GoTo NoSuch
Set sh = Sheets(SheetId)
SheetExists = True
Exit Function
NoSuch:
If Err = 9 Then SheetExists = False Else Stop
End Function
```

Comment: Copy and Pastespecial - they need to be on separate lines. I'd suggest getting in the habit of indenting your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub InsertHeader()

Dim sourceSht As Worksheet, resultSht As Worksheet

Set sourceSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set resultSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add()

'let assume first three rows of source sheet are headers
'below code does the paste special values at first row of newly created sheet.
sourceSht.Range("1:3").Copy
resultSht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

End Sub
```

Thanks,
KV Ramana

Comment: Ok, but how do I integrate this solution into my code?  My sheets are being renamed to the value of the first column, not "Sheet1".   I'm not sure how to integrate this.